# Ckeditor getSelectedElement always null

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to get the selected element in Ckeditor.  I.e. if the html is:

```
This has <a href="www.google.com">a link</a>.
```

I want to retrieve the entire `a` element when I select the link text.

As I understand it the following code:

```
editor.getSelection().getSelectedElement()
```

is supposed to do that.  But it is always returning null (no matter how much or how little I select).  I have tried various other element types and the result is always the same.

`getSelection()` by itself is not returning null.  I am able to get just the link text with

```
editor.getSelection().getNative().toString().
```

I even tried some old code that I found here:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11997&p=31833

but that resulted in the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'getRangeAt'`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was too troubleshooting the same thing. But got this code working.
Just check if it helps

```
var element = CKEDITOR.plugins.link.getSelectedLink( editor );
    if ( element )
    {
       if ( element.is( 'a' ) )
       {
          var urldata = element.getAttribute( 'href' );
          this.setValue(urldata);
        }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have switched to TinyMCE due to things like this that should be easy that are in fact easy over there.